# Can't write on the PdfDocument with Itext 7

Tags: java

I can't write in a pdf document with the object Document with itext in java. Every time i did, it gave me ClassNotDefException or ClassNotFoundException or something like that.

The code must read a pdfFile named "PathOfDraw"
If the file does not exists, then it will create once with some paragraphes inside ("Hello + code2")

But this code does not work for me :(
What did i do wrong?

Edit:
I'm catching a FileNotFoundException because if the fine "PathOfDraw" is not found, i will create once

```
//code2 is the file name;
String  pathOfDraw=pathDraw+"/"+code2+".pdf";
try{
    toClose.add(new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pathOfDraw)));
    finale.add(toClose.get(toClose.size()-1).getFirstPage());
}catch(Exception e){
    //throw new FileNotFoundException();
    PdfDocument d=new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pathOfDraw));
    Document document=new Document(d);

    Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph("Hello "+ code2);

    // Adding paragraphs to document       
    document.add(paragraph1);               
    //document.add(new Paragraph("Errore Disegno numero " + code2+ " non trovato!" ));
    document.close();
    toClose.add(new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pathOfDraw)));
    finale.add(toClose.get(toClose.size()-1).getFirstPage());
}
```

[Image of my exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GP6B.png)

Comment: Can you add the entire exception ? It would be helpful to know the name of the class not found

Comment: _Every time i did, it gave me ClassNotDefException or ClassNotFoundException or something like that._ We need the **entire**, exact error message. Why are you catching all exceptions?